# Is there a more direct way to get tag count per site?

Tags: support, tags

When I want to see what sites have questions listed with a certain tag, I go to my filters, enter the tag, and click “Just these sites”:

[image: Check tag]

This is somewhat of a roundabout way, considering I have no intention to add a filter with this tag.  Is there a more convenient way to get a count of sites with questions with a particular tag?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Except maybe SEDE where you can do a cross-site query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508533?tagname=sshfs) does show a given tag name across all sites. There is no guarantee that a tagname means the same thing across sites. Finding questions tagged `apple` might help you with your computer and teach you how to make a great pie.

```sql
---- tagname: name of the tag! "java or javascript or apple"

-- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      -- we have three sites that have borked DNS entries
      set @dbname = (case @dbname
      when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'StackExchange.Avp'
      when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'StackExchange.Avp.Meta'
      when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'net.Mathoverflow.meta'
      else @dbname
      end)
      -- and one of those doesn't want to end with .com
      if @dbname <> 'net.Mathoverflow.meta' 
         set @dbname = 'com.' + @dbname
      exec #recursesiteurl @dbname,  @res OUTPUT
   end
GO
-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#recursesiteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #recursesiteurl;
GO
create procedure #recursesiteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
       
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #recursesiteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
GO

declare @tagname nvarchar(35) = ##tagname:string##  -- 93484

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_tags ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , tagname nvarchar(35)
                            , tagcount int);
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_tags 
               select @url
               , t.tagname
               , t.count
               from tags t 
               where t.tagname = '''+ cast(@tagname as nvarchar) + ''' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai;'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '/tags/'
     + tagname
     + '|'
     + tagname as tag
     , tagcount
from #all_tags

drop table #all_tags

drop procedure #recursesiteurl
drop procedure #siteurl
```

For your example tag the result today is:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is only refreshed once a week, on Monday.

Comment: I'm aware the meaning might not be the same :)

Comment: SEDE guru strikes again!